# WebDriver. как мне произвести нажатие на checkbox если он в псевдоэлементе? И как проверить его на selected?

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

WebDriver не умеет работать с псевдоэлементами, как мне произвести нажатие на checkbox если он в псевдоэлементе? И как проверить его на selected? Интересует как это делают в компаниях автотестеры, хочу получить актуальную информацию. Если можно пример, желательно по ссылке https://rozetka.com.ua/mobile-phones/c80003/. Например checkbox в фильтре "Apple". Огромное спасибо заранее , сам новичек, хочется более развернутой информации и более актуальной. 
Пишу на Java.

Answer (score 2):

С динамическами элементами сложно всегда работать. 
Каждый раз, когда вы взаимодействуете с ним - DOM меняетеся.

Вам нужно создать свой класс, который будет описывать данный кастомный чекбос.

Я заметил один шаблон в данном конкретном случае. Если Apple(и другие тоже) выбран, появляется checked внутри `<input class="hidden" type="checkbox" checked=""`, а если не выбран, то нет

Эти элементы можно описать как список

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='sort_producer']//li")
List<WebElement> elements;
```

Достать конкрентно Apple можно пройтись по списку elements и для каждого проверять, что внутри есть текст Apple

`element.getText().contains("Apple");` // это нужный элемент. 
Нужно реализовать методы `check(WebElement el)` и `uncheck(WebElement el)`, которые бдут проверять, что если `label>input` содержит аттрибут checked, то элемент checked.

```
uncheck(WebElement el) {

    try {
    WebElement e = el.findElement(By.cssSelector("label>input")); // если не найдет, то выбросит NoSuchElementException
    if(el.getAttribute("checked") != null) // если есть аттрибут, то это означает, что чекбос выбран
        el.click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    }
}
```

**UPD** 
протестировал работоспособность и выкладываю сюда код.
Нужно вам свой кастомный декоратор писать, который будет работать с кастомными элементами. А работу с эелементами обвернуть в прокси, чтобы инициализировался еще раз, когда потеряет его в дереве.

```
    driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/mobile-phones/c80003/");
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    MyCustomElement customElement = new MyCustomElement(driver, By.id("filter_producer_69"));

    customElement.check();
    Thread.sleep(4000L);
    customElement.uncheck();
    Thread.sleep(4000L);



static class MyCustomElement {

    WebDriver driver;
    By by;

    public MyCustomElement(WebDriver driver, By by) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.by = by;
    }

    public void uncheck() {
        try {
            if(getElement().findElement(By.cssSelector("label>input")).getAttribute("checked") != null) // если есть аттрибут, то это означает, что чекбос выбран
                getElement().click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException | WebDriverException e) {
        }
    }

    public void check() {
        try {
            WebElement e = getElement().findElement(By.cssSelector("label>input"));
            if(getElement().getAttribute("checked") == null)
                getElement().click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException | WebDriverException e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * так как дерево перерисовывается, то необходимо каждый раз достатать нужный элемент.
     */
    WebElement getElement() {
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы для полноты еще добавил способ с помощью JavaScriptExecutor'а ... и если мне не изменяет память в некоторых фреймворках(JDI  и у кого то еще попроще) были уже реализованные оболочки.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor  
Да кстати не видел ранее что появляется "checked". Но к огромному  сожалению input  как я понимаю находится в псевдоэлементе или как-то так... . По этому он невидим что подтверждает данная строка возвращая false                                                                       `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#filter_producer_69 > label > input")).isDisplayed();`

Comment: @МихаилРебров Да вы абсолютно правы, кликнуть у меня получается с помощью JavaScriptExecutor'а а вот проверить на то Select он или нет, я просто не знаю как, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Вот рабочий код на клик элемента  ``

Comment: @Вова, я сегодня уже врядли успею, а завтра точно смогу написать полноценный ответ. к слову с помощью JavaScriptExecutor, можно не только кликать но и получать результат, возвращенный JavaScript'ом в Вашем тесте на Java, так что checked Вы можете проверить аналогичным способом

Comment: ну и если @SeniorPomidor, дополнит этими вариантами свой ответ, я буду только за.

Comment: @МихаилРебров@МихаилРебров 
Вот рабочий код на клик элемента который использую:
 `   WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#filter_producer_69 > label > input"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element1);`

Comment: @МихаилРебров 
Да, это очень важно для меня, если будет не сложно опишите все с мельчайшими подробностями, так как JavaScript'а не касался еще честно говоря вообще, а этот кусочек нашел на просторах интернета.

Comment: @Вова обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто. Не имеет значения нажимать на сам чекбокс или же на **Apple**.

Делаем такой вот xpath: `//*[contains(@class, 'default-title')][.='Apple']`

Моно сделать универсальный метод, где вместо Apple будем передавать нужный текст.
После клика можно проверить есть ли чекбокс вот таким xpath: `//*[contains(@class, 'default-title')][.='Apple']/parent::*[contains(@class, 'active')]`